# Can I ask for a sample contract?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

I am selling a car in the USA. I found a good resource/website for selling the car. [The website recommends I have the buyer/seller sign an "as is" document](https://www.autotrader.com/sell-car/adviser/close-the-deal/paperwork-to-close-the-deal.xhtml) but the example "as is" [link](http://www.socrates.com/c-46-as-is-addendum.aspx) is not valid anymore:

I'm having trouble finding an example as-is document. **Can i ask a question to request a good example "as is" document?** (Either a link or someone's original document with some sort of CC license that lets me use the document.)

Description of "as is" document:

> "As Is" Documentation Outside of transferring a warranty, we recommend
>   that you make it clear – in writing – that there are no implied
>   warranties when you sell your used car. This ensures that the buyer
>   acknowledges and understands that he is accepting all future
>   responsibility for the repair and maintenance of the vehicle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that would fall under the prohibition on specific legal advice.

If you don't want to pay a lawyer to provide you with a contract, you can find "boilerplate" contracts on many other sites.  (And for broken links you could always try checking [the internet archive](http://archive.org).)